# Unity progress bar for gnome-terminal?

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, gnome-terminal

One of my favorite features of unity is the progress bar the launcher overlays on the icons for various programs like the file manager, or firefox. Gnome-terminal does not have a progress bar. What do I need to do for unity to display the status of apt-get or dd etc?

If this is not possible can we at least change the icon when a prompt is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a progress bar to work will (I believe) be hard, and will have to be implemented on a case by case basis for different applications (apt-get, dd, etc.).

---

On the other hand, changing the icon when a prompt is available is easier. Assume that there exist two scripts `iconprompt` and `iconnoprompt` which change gnome-terminal's icon on execution. [I've added sample `iconprompt` and `iconnoprompt` in the end]

So, all that remains to be done is to

1. Execute `iconprompt` when a prompt becomes available.
2. Execute `iconnoprompt` when a command starts executing.

These can be accomplished by adding the lines

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='iconprompt'
trap 'iconnoprompt' DEBUG
```

to the `.bashrc` file in your homefolder.

---

The behaviour will not be as desired when you have more than one terminal open - one terminal running `apt-get` and another on which you're working. In this case icon changes will not be indicators of process completion. To handle this consider the following alternative solution:

Add

```
monitor() { iconnoprompt; "$@"; iconprompt; }
```

to `.bashrc`. To do `sudo apt-get ...`  you'll have to type `monitor sudo apt-get ...`. The icon will be different only while the monitored command is running.

I recommend this solution, also because my `iconprompt` and `iconnoprompt` scripts take about 0.1 second to execute which will create a noticeable lag for commands like `ls` and `cd`.

---

(Sample) Content of `iconnoprompt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Unity, GObject
import threading, time

launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("gnome-terminal.desktop")
launcher.set_property("progress", 0.5)
launcher.set_property("progress_visible", True)

GObject.threads_init()
loop = GObject.MainLoop()

t = threading.Thread()
t.daemon = True
t.run = loop.run
t.start()

time.sleep(0.1)
```

---

(Sample) Content of `iconprompt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Unity, GObject
import threading, time

launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("gnome-terminal.desktop")
launcher.set_property("progress", 0.)
launcher.set_property("progress_visible", False)

GObject.threads_init()
loop = GObject.MainLoop()

t = threading.Thread()
t.daemon = True
t.run = loop.run
t.start()

time.sleep(0.1)
```

---

Set executable permissions to `iconnoprompt` and `iconprompt` and put them in your `PATH`. `iconnoprompt` will add a progress-bar to the gnome-terminal icon - but the progress value has no correlation with actual progress.

Comment: Regarding the monitor function, `$@` is a bug; it should always be enclosed in double quotes, `"$@"`.

Comment: @geirha Thanks. Will update answer accordingly.